# Tengo problemas para hacer que se retraiga un menu hamburguesa, lo hice con HTML y CSS solamente, soy nuevo, espero me puedan auxiliar!

Tags: html, css

espero alguien me pueda decir que hacer, hice un menu hamburguesa que incluye logotipo, barra de busqueda y el menu... todo esta bien pero quiero hacer que se retraiga cuando haga clik en el o cuando me quite de la zona del menú o cuando haga click en otro lugar! No se quita nunca, bueno a menos que toque otra vez el icono de hamburguesa, pero si aprieto una liga o linK me lleva a donde debe pero el menu sigue abierto!! Aquí esta todo lo que puse en HTML y CSS funciona bien, pero no puedo hacer que se retraiga el menú! ***Gracias por su asesoría!*** Si pudieran mandarme los cambios se los agradecere! No se que mas poner, no me deja mandar la pregunta me dice que tengo mucho codigo y que necesito agregar  mas detalle, pero creo es fácil para alguien que sabe!

```css
header {height: 80px;}
.burguer {background: rgba(7, 7, 7, 0.781); width: 100%; height: 40px; position: fixed; z-index: 11; display: flex; justify-content: space-between;}
.nav__logo {height: 100%;}
.burguer ul {background: rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.111); display: none; z-index: 11;}
.burguer input:checked~ul {display: inline-block;}
.burguer input {display: none;}
.burguer label {box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; background: black; color: white; border-radius: 5px; width: 30px; height: 30px; line-height: 30px; font-weight: bold; text-align:center; user-select: none; position: sticky; margin-top: 3px; z-index: 11;}
.burguer label:hover {background: rgb(0, 0, 0); border: 1px solid gray; z-index: 11;}
.burguer input:checked~label {background: lightgrey; text-decoration: none;}
.burguer ul {margin-top: 0; padding: 0; width: 150px; z-index: 11;}
.burguer li {display: flexbox; /* display: block; */ background: lightgrey; margin: 0; font-size: 12px; padding: 8px; list-style: none; border-bottom: 1px solid grey; text-decoration: none; z-index: 11;}
.burguer li:hover {filter: brightness(110%);}
h2 {font-family: 'Garamond';}
.nav__lupa {display: flexbox; width: 15px;}
#search {display: flex; position: relative; height: 20px; width: 120px; margin-top: 10px; z-index: 11;}

ESTE FUE EL ESTILO, A CONTINUACION ESTA EL HTML
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="burguer">
    <img src="/Imagen/Logowebpage.png" alt="Logo" class="nav__logo" width="80" height="40">
    <div><input type="search" class="search" id="search" placeholder="Buscar"></div>
    <img src="Lupa.svg" alt="" class="nav__lupa">

    <input type="checkbox" id="menu">
    <label for="menu">☰</label>
    <ul>
      <li><a class="menu5" href="#slider">Inicio</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu5" href="#productos">Productos</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu5" href="#eventos">Eventos</a></li>
      <li><a class="menu5" href="#contacto">Contactanos</a></li>
    </ul>

  </nav>
</header>
```

Espero su respuesta! mil gracias!

Comment: Segun parece solo con HTML y CSS eso no lo puedes hacer tal como tienes el código ahora mismo. Con javascript si que podrias y es relativamente facil, pero no parece que lo contemples con solución en tu pregunta.

Comment: Estoy abierto a todo!! soy nuevo, la verdad de javascript no conozco, pero si funciona yo lo hago!! Gracias por tu comentario masterguru!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que usar Javascript. Lo más sencillo sin modificar mucho el código es
ponerle un id a la etiqueta label (id="lblMenu")

```
document.addEventListener('click', plegar)
function plegar()
  {
    event.preventDefault();
    obj = document.getElementById('menu');
    if (obj.checked)
      obj.checked = false;
    else{
      if (event.target.id == 'lblMenu')
        obj.checked = true
    }

  }
```

Se trata de tomar el control de los eventos del elemento input.
**EDITO**
Efectivamente al interceptar el evento por defecto se pierde el link, es fácil de solucionar.
Todo esto es procurando no modificar demasiado tu código:

```
document.addEventListener('click', plegar)
function plegar()
  {
    obj = document.getElementById('menu');
    if(event.target.tagName.toUpperCase() =='A'){ 
      obj.checked = false;
      return;
      }
    event.preventDefault();

    if (obj.checked)
      obj.checked = false;
    else{
      if (event.target.id == 'lblMenu')
        obj.checked = true
    }

  }
```

Lo del menu mobile first, si antes funcionaba revisa tu CSS porque no veo los query para que se active uno u otro estilo en función el ancho.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! deja lo pongo en practica!! en si si tengo un java pero lo uso para un carrusel!! deja le agrego esto!! muchas gracias!!!!

Comment: mil gracias ya se repliega el menu!! jeje pero ahora tengo un nuevo problema!! No me lleva a las secciones que tengo en la pagina! #slider, #productos, #eventos y #contacto si se cierra el menú, pero dejo de funcionar como tal!! que hago mi cuate??

Comment: incluso no se si lo mande o no en el anterior, pero ese es mobil first ya que esta arriba de los 500px se quita el menú hamburguesa y se pone normal!! pero tampoco funciona ya! Saludos y mil gracias por tus respuestas amigo!!

Comment: Muchisisimas gracias!! ya quedo!! Incluso en menú sin burguer!!! Agradezco tu tiempo y tu asesoria!!